# Check string format consist of specific words then number then specific words in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have requirement to check if email in specific format and consists of specific words then number then specific words
For example

```
 "Auto_gen_1234@mail.com"
 "Auto_gen_7302@mail.com"
 "Auto_gen_8928@mail.com"
```

"auto_gen" is fixed and "@mail.com" is fixed also but number is variable so do you know if i can check if email in this format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really easy to make a regular expression to get matches:

```
        string[] input = new string[6]
        {
            "Auto_gen_1234@mail.com", // match
            "Auto_gen_7302@mail.com", // match
            "Auto_gen_8928@mail.com", // match
            "Auto_gen_12345@mail.com", // not a match
            "Auto_gen_72@mail.com", // not a match
            "Auto_gen_Bob@mail.com" // not a match
        };

        string pattern = @"Auto_gen_\d{4}@mail.com";  //\d{4} means 4 digits
        foreach (string s in input)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Input {0} is valid",s));
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine (string.Format("Input {0} is  not valid",s));
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```